# How to log in to Domjudge after setting the password during installation

Tags: authentication

I am trying to install Domjudge on my VPS. I ran `./configure`, `make` and `config database`.

At this point I should be able to login at  `/public/login.php` with the user/pass: `judgehost/judge` but it doesn't log me in.  Instead it gives a "Not authenticated" error. I have also tried `/jury` with user/pass: `admin/123456`  with no successs.

User "judge" and password "123456" are the right credentials because I changed them in the database.  If I type the wrong password, I get the error: "Invalid username or password supplied. Please try again or contact a staff member." I think it is not about the connection to the database or the wrong password.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que).